# set Interval in c3js chart on axis

Tags: d3.js, charts, c3.js

c3js charts takes years on 'y axis' automatically, but it interval with `.5` years. How do i remove that type of interval. I tried to find out from documentation and other source but in vain.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not seen an elegant way of doing this, but here is what I've been using.

In `chart.axis.y.tick` you can choose which values get displayed.

```
      y: {
          tick: {
                    format: function (d) {if (d != "2" && d != "6" && d != "10" && d != "14" && d != "18" ) return d + "%"}
          }
      }
```

I've taken every second tick off my y axis.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I changed to Highcharts. this chart pissed me off with client requirements. and data was coming from ajax json. this drives me off.